# Drop Dublicates, if they are in a row in Python

Tags: python

I got list like:

`[1,1,5,4,6,6,5]`

and I want to drop the element of list, if its get repeated.

Output:
`[1,5,4,6,5]`

I can only find solution for "normal" Duplicate-Problems.

Comment: make a set to remove duplicates, list(set([1,1,5,4,6,6,5]))

Comment: or dictionary if you want to keep the order :list(dict.fromkeys([1,1,5,4,6,6,5]).keys())

Comment: @amirhm, read the question again.  Only drop sequential dupliates.

Comment: @amirhm this will not keep the order and remove all the duplicates, not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Guy in second comment I added the if you want to keep the order use dic and gave example

Comment: @amirhm it will still remove all duplicates. The expected output has two `5`. Only sequential duplicates are removed.

Comment: @Guy ok, then it is even more simpler, I guess the question is edited, anyhow if a is the list: `[v  for idx, v in enumerate(a) if (idx==0) or v != a[idx - 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and just pull the key for each group.

```
from itertools import groupby

[k for k, _ in groupby([1,1,5,4,6,6,5])]
# returns:
[1, 5, 4, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over pairs with `zip` and build a new list

```
lst = [1, 1, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5]
lst = [x for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if x != y] + [lst[-1]]
print(lst) # [1, 5, 4, 6, 5]
```